# Detect HTTPS using SharpPCap

Tags: https, packet, sharppcap

I am using SharpPCap to filter packets. Does anyone know how to detect if a packet is for a secured http connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to sniff the traffic from the start of the TCP session to observe the SSL handshake go back and forth.  Once the encrypted session is set up, any individual packet is going to be indistinguishable from random noise.

To discover otherwise is to find a major flaw in the symmetric cipher.  (Yes, the encryption really is that good.)

Of course, having a destination of port 443 is a hint that you are looking at an https connection...  But that is just a convention.

Comment: What do I use to trace back ?